# android EditText: hint disappears with inputType="textCapCharacters"

Tags: android, xml

This might be a bug or I just don't get why, but it seems that setting `inputType="textCapCharacters"` (or any other inputType) on a `EditText` makes disappearing the hint in combination with `gravity="center"`.

The following is an extract of my xml where the `LinearLayout` visible on the Image below is defined:

**a) Without** `inputType="textCapCharacters"`

```
(...)
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lin_cond1"
    android:layout_below="@id/v_cond_line1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/rb_cond_stake_normal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/define_stake"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et_cond_enter_stake_normal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et_cond_currencies"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/currency"
        />
</LinearLayout>
(...)
```

**Result**

[image]

**b) With** `inputType="textCapCharacters"`

```
(...)
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lin_cond1"
    android:layout_below="@id/v_cond_line1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/rb_cond_stake_normal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/define_stake"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et_cond_enter_stake_normal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et_cond_currencies"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/currency"
        />
</LinearLayout>
(...)
```

**Result**

[image]

What I tried and didn't worked:
- making the hint text also in capitals
- putting `inputType="textCapCharacters"` at different positions

What works, but Is not desired:
- (as seen around here) remove `gravity="center"`. But why does it not work only in combination?   Leaving the `gravity` without the `inputType` works normal.

So is there any solution to have either a inputType and the gravity?

Comment: Definitely looking like a bug to me. Tried it on Android 3.0+? Or perhaps 4.0+?

Comment: Just tried it with Android 4.0, it works! Had it on 2.3.3 before, because some "tester" I know have this version on their phone.

Comment: You may have to settle for non-centered text on 2.3.3, then. Sad life of an Android developer. :(